# MPI_Free_mem fails with a segmentation fault using OpenMPI

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi, intel, openmpi

I am using OpenMPI with the Intel C++ compiler on an Intel Ubuntu system. Whenever I try to replace `new[]` and `delete[]` calls with `MPI_Alloc_mem` and `MPI_Free_mem` calls, respectively, I always get a segmentation fault.

The `MPI_Alloc_mem` calls return `MPI_SUCCESS`. The segmentation fault occurs on the call to `MPI_Free_mem`. The `MPI_Alloc_mem` calls are with `MPI_INFO_NULL`. I explicitly typecast the `void**` and `void*` arguments in `MPI_Alloc_mem` and `MPI_Free_mem`respectively.

I have no idea why this happens. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your code contains error. Probably on line #42.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you are going to use MPI-2 one-sided communication, there is absolutely no need to replace C++ memory management operators with MPI calls.

Second, the correct usage of `MPI_ALLOC_MEM` and `MPI_FREE_MEM` in C/C++ is as follows:

```
int *arr;

MPI_Alloc_mem(sizeof(int)*1000, MPI_INFO_NULL, &arr); // <-- here arr by address
...
MPI_Free_mem(arr);                                    // <-- here arr by value
```